# Inserting particular string into text (bash sed)

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Hi I am looking for a way to insert , into a text by using sed command.
I've found a way to do it just once or in like every 5 characters.

However I have a text (ex containing 10 characters here) I would like to put , after first 2 characters, then 3characters after that. And it continues till the text end.

So text I have would be like

```
abcdefghij
```

and output I am looking for would be like

```
ab,cde,fg,hij,
```

Is there any way to do this kind of inserting by sed?

Comment: What if the length isn't a multiple of 5? What should the end look like?

Comment: Sorry I should have said the length is a multiple of 5 in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strings with a length that's a multiple of 5:

```
echo abcdefghij | sed 's/\(..\)\(...\)/\1,\2,/g'
```

Comment: It didnt work for me.. 
I have got similar one 
echo 'abcdefghij' | sed -e 's/'^\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{3\}\)/\1,\2,/g'
but ended up like
ab,cde,fghij

Comment: Shawn's command works for me.  @gggert I suggest you copy-and-paste it _exactly_ and try again.  If it still doesn't work, document _exactly_ what happened including the full unaltered text of any output and full unaltered text of any error messages.

Comment: @gggert Your RE doesn't match that string at all because it doesn't have parentheses in it. Plus since you anchor it to the beginning of the line, even if it did match, it'd only do so once.

Comment: @Shawn 
Thank you for clarification. I actually executed the command in CLI directly. It worked after I put it into a .sh file executed it instead.